# Can a +/- counter component be written as an html form?

Tags: html, forms, reactjs, semantic-markup

I'm building a ReactJS +/- counter component, and I'm wondering if, regarding HTML markup and semantics, it'd be OK to code it like this, as a form with 2 input and 1 output children :

```
<form>
  <input type='button' value='+' onClick={this.increment} />
  <input type='button' value='-' onClick={this.decrement} />
  <output />
</form>
```

Thanks for helping.

Silvère

Comment: "OK" in what sense?

Comment: a `form` is most often used for submitting information to a web server, the question is what is "OK" even mean?

Comment: When I say 'would it be OK ?', I mean 'would it make sense, from a semantic point of view ?'.